# Is there any way to convert all the PDF annotations into pdf content using itext?

Tags: pdf, itext, pdf-generation, itext7

I am trying to write a content over the annotation using itext. But the overlay content display only bellow the annotation. Also i don't want to remove my annotation.

```java
PdfReader.removeAnnotations();
```

I like to write over the annotation or need to make annotation as fixed.

```java
over = stamp.getOverContent(pageNumber);
```

getOverContent will write content under the annotation.

please help this problem.

My Example PDF :
I need to write text over this annotation
[image: Annotation over Need to write Text]

Comment: How about creating a free text annotation with your desired content, added to the annotations array in a position to be displayed atop?

Comment: First you have to flatten the annotations (check documentation to see if iText supports this functionality) then you can add content on top of them

Comment: As far as I know iText7 only contains an explicit method for flattening form fields. But it should be easy deriving a method from that which flattens all annotations.